# Issue with getFullYear from datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to retrieve the full year from a date in a textbox, but it's not returning if the day is more than 12 (so i suspect it's a date format issue), but how can I get this working?

```
   $(function() {
        $("#dateInput").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                var birthDate = new Date($(this).val()).getFullYear();
                alert(birthDate); 
            },
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            constrainInput: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: new Date()
        });
    });
```

see here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JCRs/12/

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use Uppercase `MM` instead of lowercase `mm` and it should work. So your date format should be:

```
dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datepicker.parseDate` function which will parse the date ***according to the specified format***:

> $.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings ) - Extract a date
>   from a string value with a specified format.

The `onSelect` function must be changed to this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        dateText,
        inst.settings
    );
    alert(date.getFullYear());
}
```

`datepicker.parseDate` function expects the date format in the first parameter. The best way to supply this value is to use the explicitly specified date format or fall back to default date format.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/5JCRs/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `dateFormat` option value to 'yy':

```
$( "#dateInput" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy" });
```

Or, if you are using a `regional` setting:

```
$.datepicker.regional["it"] = {
    //...
    , dateFormat: "yy"
    //...
}
```

References [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Answer (score 0):

It is just difference of date formatting in JQuery and Javascript. In javascript the possible date formats, when you provide dateString to `new Date(dateString)` are

```
MM-dd-yyyy
yyyy/MM/dd
MM/dd/yyyy
MMMM dd, yyyy
MMM dd, yyyy
```

You can provide dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' for JQuery then it would work, which is equivalent to MM/dd/yyyy in javascript.